# Re=authenticate user with sorcery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I'm using the sorcery gem and trying to re-authenticate a user to change their password in the "my account" section. So basically there's old_password, password and password_confirmation on the form. So basically, the user is already logged in, but I wanted to put an additional authentication check to reset the user's password for an extra level of security.

My question is: how do I achieve this with Sorcery? I was browsing their source code and came across 'authenticate' method on what I thought was the user object, but how do I call this (note I"m relatively new to rails and still coming to terms with the ruby syntax)

This is what I've got:

```
if (@password_reset.valid? && current_user.authenticate(@password_reset.email, @password_reset.old_password))
```

And the relevant part of the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez, I'm surprised nobody answered this question, it ended up being quite simple. It turns out that all I had to do was call the class method instead of using the instance as shown below.

```
User.authenticate(@password_reset.email, @password_reset.old_password, false)
```

Comment: This works, but what does the last parameter do i.e. false?

Comment: it's been awhile since I've looked at this. to be honest I can't remember.I tried to go back and figure it out but couldn't find the project this came from.

Comment: I looked at the source code again, which I think is at this link:  https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb. I couldn't see why the third parameter was there, perhaps it's left from an earlier Sorcery release. I suspect it had something to do with remember-me functionality. I guess you could drop the third parameter now?

Comment: Taking out false appears to make no difference.